# MySQL: Query distinct column with two different column dates

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have the following result from a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, 
                IF(ra.status = 1, created_datetime, 'No record') AS ACTIVATED, 
                IF(ra.status = 0, created_datetime, 'No record') AS DE_ACTIVATED 
FROM   accounts ra 
WHERE  user_id IN ( 12345678 ); 

+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id  | ACTIVATED           | DE_ACTIVATED        |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 12345678 | No record           | 2013-04-28 02:32:36 |
| 12345678 | 2013-03-28 02:32:36 | No record           |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I am trying to have only 1 row of record, combining the activated and de-activated. Basically, making it like this.

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id  | ACTIVATED           | DE_ACTIVATED        |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 12345678 | 2013-03-28 02:32:36 | 2013-04-28 02:32:36 |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Any help is much appreciated as I build my query ninja skills.

Regards

Comment: What's the correlation between the two? Why not just get the `MAX` of both columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `MAX` of both conditions, but make the "false" condition evaluate to `null`. Then wrap it in `COALESCE` so if the calcualted `MAX` is null it'll be replaced with `no record`:

```
SELECT user_id,
  COALESCE(MAX(IF(ra.status = 1, created_datetime, null)), 'No record') AS Activated,
  COALESCE(MAX(IF(ra.status = 0, created_datetime, null)), 'No record') AS Deactivated
FROM accounts ra
WHERE user_id IN (12345678)
```

And if you'll be querying more than one user, add this to the end:

```
GROUP BY user_id
```